# printWorkingDirectory() gives null

Tags: java, ftp-client

I have written below piece of code to insert Excel records into a db table. Excel file is on ftp server.
Basically I am changing directory first abd retrievig file stream.

```
readExcel(String test, String filename) {
    client.changeWorkingDirectory("/"+test);
    is =  client.retrieveFileStream(filename");
    //do the processing
}
```

above code works well for one time. But now I want use above code in loop and upload multiple files. I did that and found that only first file got processed properly, the second file got stuck just above `client.retrieveFileStream()` method.
after I used `printWorkingDirectory()` method before and after `changeWorkingDirectory()` for first file in loop it gave correct directory befor and after. but for second time in loop it is giving null both the times and code gets stuck before. `retrieveFileStream()`.

according to me issue is because `changeWorkingDirectory()` is being called multiple times.

Comment: What is the **client** ? How do you call this method ?

Comment: The `client` appears to be an `FTPClient` of `apache.commons.net`… Am I right?

Comment: Yes ...i am really sorry i did not give enough info.

Comment: that client is active ftp connnection. client is defined as global variable and is already set before calling this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`changeWorkingDirectory()` returns a boolean to indicate success or failure, but it hides the cause of the failure when it fails. If you look at the source code:

```
public boolean changeWorkingDirectory(String pathname) throws IOException
{
    return FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(cwd(pathname));
}
```

It merely wraps the call to `cwd`.

Now if you want the cause of failure you can write your function like this:

```
readExcel(String test, String filename) {
    int returnCode = client.cwd("/"+test);
    if ( FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion( returnCode ) ) {
        is =  client.retrieveFileStream(filename");
        //do the processing
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Cannot cd to " + filename + " errorcode="+returnCode);
    }
}
```

Then just look for the meaning of the code you received.

Comment: should i call cwd method before changedirectory or after changedirectory method.

Comment: first time FTp reply was 250 - requested file action is okay. second time in loop says 257 - pathname created. can you please tell me what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today:

Looping with `client.retrieveFileStream()` once printed the right working directory but the second time `client.printWorkingDirectory()` only printed `null`.

In my case I'd just changed the type of file download from `client.retrieveFile()` to `client.retrieveFileStream()`, which requires `client.completePendingCommand()` to be called afterwards. The documentation says:

> If this is not done, subsequent commands may behave unexpectedly.

Changing the code you posted, it would look like this:

```
readExcel(String test, String filename) {
    client.changeWorkingDirectory("/"+test);
    is =  client.retrieveFileStream(filename");
    //do the processing

    if(client.completePendingCommand()) {
        //File transfer successful
    } else {
        //File transfer failed
    }
}
```

> But now I want use above code in loop and upload multiple files.

I'm aware this question was already answered, so this is for everyone else who finds it:

If you want to upload/download multiple files (and if all the files should go into/are in the same folder!) you should only change the working directory at the very beginning because:

Once you log into the server, it'll set the working directory to the root directory (e.g. `\`). If you then loop through the files and try to change the directory every time, this'll happen:

- First loop iteration: It'll switch to the directory you want, e.g.
  `\subdir`.
- Second loop iteration: The current directory is still `\subdir`, so it'll try to switch to `\subdir\subdir`, which might or might not exist.
- Third loop iteration: The current directory is `\subdir\subdir` and it'll try switching to `\subdir\subdir\subdir`.

Once you log out and back in again, the working directory is going to be the root (e.g. `\`) again.